# Datagrid checkbox styling

Tags: wpf, datagrid, checkbox, styles

Hello
First sorry for my english.
I have started recently my first project on wpf. I´m styling a custom DataGrid who have been defined programatically (the xaml code doesn´t exists).
I have styled all that i need in my datagrid control except a checkbox that i wrapped inside.
The problem is that in other place of my application i defined a checkbox style how are applying correctly but i can´t apply inside my datagrid.
Actually my datagrid doesn´t throw syntax errors but when the datagrid runs the checkbox styles doesn´t apply.
The style code look like this (its defined in a stylesheet)

```
... <Setter Property="DataGridCheckBoxColumn.ElementStyle">
        <Setter.Value>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">

                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource NormalBorderBrush}"/>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">


                            <BulletDecorator Background="Transparent">
                                <BulletDecorator.Bullet>
                                    <Grid Width="13" Height="13">
                                        <Border x:Name="Border" Background="Pink" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" CornerRadius="2,2,2,2"/>
                                        <Path x:Name="CheckMark" Stroke="Green" StrokeThickness="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="False" Data="M1.5000001,1.5833334 L9.7920001,9.6666667 M1.5420001,9.6666667 L9.7083333,1.5000001" Margin="1" ClipToBounds="False" StrokeEndLineCap="Round" StrokeStartLineCap="Round"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                </BulletDecorator.Bullet>
                                <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" RecognizesAccessKey="True"/>
                            </BulletDecorator>

                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </Setter.Value>

    </Setter>...
```

Its exactly the same that it`s applying in the apliccation.
I´ve read a lot about it but i can´t to apply it, i tried, also, setting the setter property to "DatagridBoundColum.ElementStyle" and also to "CellStyle" but it doesn´t work.
Any suggest??
Thank a lot.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Do it like you would do in xaml:

```xml
<UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="CheckBoxTemplate">
        <CheckBox Style="{StaticResource AnyResourceKeyInApplciation}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" />
```

```cs
this.dataGrid.Columns.Add(new DataGridTemplateColumn
                              {
                                  CellTemplate = this.Resources["CheckBoxTemplate"] as DataTemplate
                              }
                         );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
<Controls:DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Homme"  Binding="{Binding Homme}">
                        <Controls:DataGridCheckBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="CheckBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type CheckBox}}">
                                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="4,0,0,0"/>
                            </Style>
                        </Controls:DataGridCheckBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                    </Controls:DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
```

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for your Reply vorrtex.

I didn´t apply it exactly  but it helped me to find the solution, however i would have liked not to modify the VB code and only to modify it the xaml style tag.

I find an object how simplify this task. The syntax it´s the following:

```
column2.ElementStyle = Application.Current.FindResource("CheckBoxStyle")
```

It´s applying style ok inside the datagrid. But actually it´s placing at left border of the cell. I´ll try to find why.

Thanks again.